# ExpressJS - Using Q

Tags: node.js, express, q, node-request

For a certain route, I have the following code:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var matches = db.get('matches');
  var id = req.params.id;

  matches.find({id: id}, function(err, obj){
    if(!err) {
      if(obj.length === 0) {
        var games = Q.fcall(GetGames()).then(function(g) {
          console.log("async back");
          res.send(g);
        }
          , function(error) {
            res.send(error);
          });
      }
      ...
});
```

The function `GetGames` is defined as follows:

```
function GetGames() {
  var url= "my-url";
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error) {
      console.log("Returned with code "+ response.statusCode);
      return new Q(body);
    }
  });
}
```

I'm using the `request` module to send a HTTP GET request to my URL with appropriate parameter, etc.

When I load `/:id`, I see "Returned with code 200" logged, but "async back" is not logged. I'm also not sure that the response is being sent.

Once `GetGames` returns something, I want to be able to use that returned object in the route for `/:id`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GetGames` is an async function write it in node.js callback pattern:

```
function GetGames(callback) {
  var url= "my-url";
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error) {
      console.log("Returned with code "+ response.statusCode);
      return callback(null,body)
    }
    return callback(error,body)
  });
}
```

Then use [`Q.nfcall`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node) to call the above function and get back a promise:

```
 Q.nfcall(GetGames).then(function(g) {
 })
 .catch()
```